# VB.Net, EventArgs, ByRef and ByVal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, byref, eventargs, byval

In VB.Net, I have an object named `WorkflowButtonEventArgs` that inherits from `System.EventArgs`.

The `WorkflowButtonEventArgs` class contains two `ByRef` Properties. These are objects that are in memory, and I do not want them duplicated or copied in any way.

Can I pass the `WorkflowButtonEventArgs` object `ByVal` in VB.Net and have it still preserve the two `ByRef` definitions in `WorkflowButtonEventArgs`?

Specifically, if I pass it ByVal:

```
Dim e As New WorkflowButtonEventArgs(...) ' e has some ByRef properties

RaiseEvent SomeEventName(e) ' e is passed ByVal
```

Will the `ByRef` Properties/Members in `e` (`WorkflowButtonEventArgs` class) not be copied or duplicated in memory?

Long-story-short: Can I pass `e` `ByVal`, or do I need to pass it `ByRef` since it contains `ByRef` Properties?

Comment: By "ByRef" Property, do you mean a Property for a reference type, such as a Class?

Comment: What is a "ByRef" property?  As far as I am aware, the ByRef keyword does not apply to properties nor can it be used when declaring a property.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I pass e "ByVal", or do I need to pass it "ByRef" since it contains "ByRef" Properties?

Yes.  The objects pointed to by the reference will not get copied, even if your `EventArgs` is passed ByVal.

Answer (score 1):

Reference objects wont be duplicated in memory. The `ByRef` keyword on a parameter only means that you can change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

Comment: To All: My apologies for the error in the original post. The Properties are to Reference-type variables (specifically classes/objects). It sounds like I can pass the event arg "ByVal", and the reference-type Properties in the event arg will not be duplicated in memory. Sound right?

Comment: Reference objects wont be duplicated in memory. ByVal or ByRef does not matter

Comment: Ok... that answers my question. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve your goal would be to create a singleton that would store the two properties.